# Click on dropdown item, open different dropdown elsewhere on navigation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

The very top level of my navigation is a horizontal bar of buttons. When the user hovers over the top level, a second level dropdown toggles on. Is there any way to program my navigation so that when the user clicks on a particular second-level item, it will close the second-level container and automatically open a different second-level dropdown elsewhere on the navigation, as if on hover??

In other words, say my top level navigation bar is six horizontal buttons. When the user hovers over button four, they will see a dropdown of various selections. When they click on a particular selection inside that dropdown, it will automatically close the button four dropdown container and open the dropdown container under top-level button five, as if the user was hovering on it?

(I have searched, but turned up nothing I identified as similar to my issue.)

EDIT: adding code per request.

Button four dropdown html:

```
  <li class="top-level"><a href="division4.html" class="top-link">Division4</a>
    <div class="drop_1col-topA" title="Menu by category">
      <div class="col_A">
        <ul>
           <li class="second-level"><a href="product1.html" class="second-link1" tabindex="1">Product1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="second-level"><a href="product2.html" class="second-link1" tabindex="2">Product2</a>
          </li>
          <li class="second-level"><a href="product3.html" class="second-link1" tabindex="3">Product3</a>
          </li>
          <li class="second-level"><a href="#" class="second-link1" tabindex="4">Division 5 Products</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </li>
```

Button five dropdown html:

```
  <li class="top-level"><a href="division5.html" class="top-link">Division5</a>
    <div class="drop_1col-topA" title="Menu by category">
      <div class="col_A">
        <ul>
           <li class="second-level"><a href="product1.html" class="second-link1" tabindex="1">Product1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="second-level"><a href="product2.html" class="second-link1" tabindex="2">Product2</a>
          </li>
          <li class="second-level"><a href="product3.html" class="second-link1" tabindex="3">Product3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </li>
```

I would like it if the user clicks on "Division 5 Products" under button four dropdown and it automatically opens the button five drowdown, as if the user was hovering on it.

Comment: Please add your code you tried

Comment: Have you even tried? Where's your attempted code?

Comment: I have no idea how to make a separate dropdown open on click as if on hover without the user hovering on it and losing it the moment they moved their cursor. I wouldn't know where to begin. (Sorry, I'm not the most advanced developer yet!)